# Preferred/Better way to call functions?

Tags: javascript, function

Which example below is the better way to call functions, organize your code in JavaScript? Does one way take up more memory, time, etc, than the other?

Example 1:

```
function one() {
    console.log("stuff");
    two();
}

function two() {
    console.log("stuff");
    three();
}

function three() {
    console.log("stuff");
}

one();
```

Example 2:

```
function one() {
    console.log("stuff");
}

function two() {
    console.log("stuff");
}

function three() {
    console.log("stuff");
}

one();
two();
three();
```

Comment: It depends on your needs. The second example allows you to call each function by itself, the first one links them together.

Comment: The first method uses more stack space.

Comment: The meaning is different. It might look the same in this small example, and it will result in the same output in this case, but the meaning is different. In *real* code you'll know when one approach fits the problem while another does not. There is *no issue* with "memory" or "time" in either case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between these two approaches is that in the first example every time you call function one() you force a chain of calls to two() and then to three() so they are all bundled, in the second example you separated them and therefor you are free to call them separately.
If each of the functions encapsulate a logic that is self contained, it's better to avoid example 1, and that will give you the freedom to reuse the code in function two and three.

In terms of memory example one is more memory intense since at a certain point when you arrive at function three() the memory stack will be one -> two -> three, and in example two there will never be more than one function call in the memory stack.